# How can I make this lambda work?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have this code:

```
        String temp = txtForm.Rtf;

        foreach (ReplaceStrut rs in replaceArray) {
            temp = temp.Replace(rs.getNeedle(), rs.getReplacement());
        }
        if (this.InvokeRequired) {
            this.Invoke(temp => txtForm.Rtf = temp);
        } else {
            txtForm.Rtf = temp;
        }
```

But it won't compile. It complains about two things, "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type" and, "A local variable named 'temp' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a difference meaning to 'temp', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Both error are on the lambda line. How can I make this work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => txtForm.Rtf = temp))
```

Comment: Never seen the syntax used like this  :p  Not sure if I like it or not.

Comment: The `new Action(() => ...)` syntax is identical in terms of the generated IL to `(Action)(() => ...)`.

Answer (score 6):

The "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type" error is occurring because lambda expressions do not have types. The compiler usually infers the type from the target of the assignment, but this is not possible with `Invoke` because it takes a `System.Delegate`. Casting the lambda expression will solve this problem.

It isn't necessary to declare `temp` as a parameter of your lambda expression. The expression will be able to refer to `temp` from the containing scope.

Change your `Invoke` line to the following and it should work:

```
this.Invoke((Action)(() => txtForm.Rtf = temp));
```

Make sure you are referencing the `System.Core` assembly for the above line, otherwise you'll get an error saying "Using the generic type 'System.Action' requires '1' type arguments".

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Invoke((Action) () => txtForm.Rtf = something); // where something is free
```

Comment: this doesn't quite work. I found out lamba's actually have access to current scope variables so passing it temp is unnecessary. Fix your answer and I'll mark it as the right one

Comment: Good point :)  Obviously some argument would have to be passed then :p

Comment: No, you have to use temp, not 'something' Something is in neither scope, therefor it'd have to be passed.

Comment: For the cast to work, an extra set of parentheses are required around the lambda expression.